# Can we cancel a push notification from application on iOS5?

Tags: ios5, push

On iOS5, the push notification shows on the top bar and not block user. When the push notification is showing and user click our application but not the push bar, our app will launch normally. However, we want to cancel the push notification at that time. Is it possible ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. There is no way you can manipulate sent notifications as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly longer answer:

Once a push request has been sent to the Apple Push Notification servers, thats it. It disappears into their system and they will then try to deliver it on a 'best effort' basis. You receive no feedback about its status or any ability to change/delete it.

The only form of feedback you can get is about which devices do not wish to receive push notifications that you tried to send to.

If you want to send delayed notifications which can be cancelled/modified at later data, either write you own solution, or use some pre-existing solution (e.g Urban Airship).